# Is there any constant $c$ satisfying the inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, upper-lower-bounds, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Is there any positive constant $c\in \mathbb{R}$ such that for any nonzero $a,b\in \mathbb{R}^n$,

$$\frac{1}{2}\|a-b\|^2-\frac{1}{\pi}\sqrt{\|a\|^2\|b\|^2-\langle a,b\rangle^2}+\langle a,b\rangle\frac{\cos^{-1}(\rho)}{\pi}\geq c\|a-b\|^2$$

where $\rho=\frac{\langle a,b\rangle}{\|a\|\,\|b\|}$.

I checked extreme cases where $a,b$ are orthogonal or in the same or opposite directions. It seems that there is a positive $c$, satisfying the above inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have two vectors $a$, $b$ enclosing an angle $\phi\in[0,\pi]$, and are told to prove that
$${1\over2}|a-b|^2-{1\over\pi}|a|\,|b|\sin\phi+|a|\,|b|\cos\phi\,{\phi\over\pi}\geq c|a-b|^2$$
for a universal $c>0$. This claim can be written as
$$|a|\,|b|{\sin\phi-\phi\cos\phi\over\pi}\leq\left({1\over2}-c\right)|a-b|^2\ .$$
Now one can verify (by drawing the graphs) that
$$0\leq{\sin\phi-\phi\cos\phi\over\pi}\leq{1\over2}(1-\cos\phi)\qquad(0\leq\phi\leq\pi)\ .$$
Therefore it is sufficient to prove
$${1\over2}|a|\,|b|(1-\cos\phi)\leq\left({1\over2}-c\right)|a-b|^2\ .\tag{1}$$
Note that by the cosine theorem
$$|a-b|^2=|a|^2+|b|^2-2|a|\,|b|\cos\phi=\bigl(|a|-|b|\bigr)^2+2|a|\,|b|(1-\cos\phi)\ .$$
This proves
$${1\over2}|a|\,|b|(1-\cos\phi)\leq{1\over4}|a-b|^2\ ,$$
so that $(1)$ is true with $c={1\over4}$.

Answer (score -1):

Your inequality is equivalent to  find $c\ge 0$ such that  for all $\theta $, $$
\|a\|\|b\|\cos(\theta)\theta\geq \|a\|\|b\|\sin(\theta)+{\pi}(c-0.5)||a-b||^2$$
($\langle a,b\rangle=\|a\|\|b\|\cos(\theta)$)
 so 
the inequality should hold with $c=0$

$\|a-b\|^2=\|a\|^2+\|b\|^2-2\|a\|\|b\|\cos(\theta)$
replacing we would get $$\|a\|\|b\|(\sin(\theta)-\theta\cos(\theta)+\pi\cos(\theta))\le \frac{\pi}{2}(\|a\|^2+\|b\|^2)$$ so by AGM inequality for $\|a\|=\|b\|$ we require $\sin(\theta)-\theta\cos(\theta)+\pi\cos(\theta)-\pi\le 0$ which isn't true for all $\theta$.

Comment: LHS is $||a||||b||(\sin(\theta)-\theta\cos(\theta)+\pi\cos(\theta))\leq$, and the inequality is true as I plotted it.

Comment: the inequality is for all $\theta$!

Comment: Be careful, $\theta$ is $cos^{-1}$ whose range is $[0,\pi]$

Comment: You should  have mentionned that:

Comment: I did not use $\theta$. You used $\theta$ instead of $\cos^{-1}$ so I did not need to mention it in the problem

Comment: The $c$ though would depend on the range of $\theta $...

Comment: After some examples (plots) the $c$ you want for all $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ (this range makes sense since we have a dot product) is $0.25,$ equality is when $\theta=\pi$ and $\|a\|=\|b\|$. Maybe someone could formalize.